# C modulus returning negative number

Tags: c, int, modulus, negative-number, int128

I have data type `unsigned __int128 data;` so I don't think this is a type issue, but I have no idea why it is occuring

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    unsigned __int128 z = 1911602146;
    unsigned __int128 n = 4003562209;

    //case 1
        unsigned __int128 result = fmod((pow(z, 2)  * 2), n);
        printf("%d\n", result);

    //case 2
        unsigned __int128 result_2 = fmod(pow(z, 2), n);
        printf("%d\n", result_2);
}
```

returns:

```
-669207835 => this is the correct option and it should be 7629321670
-480306461
```

Comment: Why are you using floating-point functions on your unsigned integer data?

Comment: Try `result = (z*z* 2) % n`.

Comment: this still returns a negative

Comment: `%d` is only for printing `int`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First avoid the floating-point trip during the calculation.
Then, only for printing, convert the result (which is < 10^10) to double in order to use the printf function

```
unsigned __int128 z = 1911602146;
unsigned __int128 n = 4003562209;

unsigned __int128 result = (z * z * 2) % n;
printf("%.0lf\n", (double)result);

unsigned __int128 result_2 = (z * z) % n;
printf("%.0lf\n", (double)result_2);
```

That should give you

```
3625759213
3814660711
```

(you cannot get 7629321670 anyway as a result, since it is bigger than the modulo operand, 'n')

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("%d\n", result);
//      ^^
```

`%d` expects an `int`. You're passing it an `unsigned __int128` instead, resulting in undefined behavior. Most likely, `printf` is taking part of the representation of `result` and interpreting it as an `int`.

I don't know what the right format specifier would be, but you should find the right one and use it. Also, you shouldn't be using floating-point functions on your data; you're losing precision there.

Comment: when I use the modulus operator I get error: invalid operands to binary expression ('double' and 'double')
                unsigned __int128 result = (pow(z, 2)  * 2) % n;

Comment: you are correct though because it's throwing a warning about the __int128 type

Comment: is there an exponent integer function?

Comment: @KendallWeihe: No. Use `z * z`.

Comment: I think what I'll do is just write a splice function that splices the digits from __int128 into an integer array and then print them out

Comment: @user2357112: Exponent function for integers: `int powi(int n, int power) { if(power < 0) return 0; else { int ret = 1; while(power--) ret *= n; return ret; } }` ;).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `__int128` is a [GNU CC extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html), and thus there's no portable way to handle them, neither a portable way to print them.

As it happens to be, there's (ironically...) no support, not even from Glibc, for `printf`ing(), `__int128`s nor `unsigned __int128`s.

The only alternative you have is to write your own functions to print them out in decimal, or better yet, in hexadecimal, because this kind of large integers can get pretty unreadable in decimal too easily.

BTW, this is undefined behaviour:

```
printf("%d\n", result);
```

Because the `"%d"` specifier expects an `int` as argument, nothing less, nothing more, nothing else.

I hope this has led some light on you!

Comment: I think I'll write a splice function the splices the digits into an array and then print the array

Comment: @KendallWeihe: If that fits your approach then it's okay ;).